# Finding different subspaces including a given one consisting of rank-1 matrices as generators.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the subspace A of the Matrix Vector Space
$$
A=\langle 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0   
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1   
\end{pmatrix}
\rangle
$$
we have the following inclusion of subspaces
$$
A \subseteq \langle 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0   
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0   
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0   
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1   
\end{pmatrix}
\rangle = B
$$
Now, the reason I consider this inclusion is that I want to see the subspaces whose generators are rank-1 matrices and include A. The way I found these rank-1 matrices in B is just decomposing the matrices in A in an obvious way (just decompose through addition).

My question is that can I find another subspace C such that the generators of C are all rank-1 matrices and $A\subseteq C$ and possible lower dimensional subspace than B?

I tried to use Singular Value Decomposition to decompose the matrices A in a different way so far but that did not lead anywhere. Can you guys help me with this? Is there any method to do this or any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.